# Mac OS SSD failure/corruption

Tags: osx, ssd, corruption

I was trying out new OS on my Macbook, now I started to install elementary on my primary drive and force quit the installation in middle.. which resulted in bad GPT partition.

Now, when I contacted apple support they made me erase the drive, but it did not work, the drive is detected when I boot up my mac with linux OR macOS but as I try to format it, the disk just vanishes.

I tried to perform fsck on ubuntu:

`fsck -a /dev/sda1`

and this was the output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sda` might be useful too

Comment: Does [this suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/102815/296109) from [apple.SE] for completely erasing the internal disk help at all? IMO you should look to a complete erase of the partition table before trying to continue.

Comment: Yeah.. I tried that, but i cannot erase my disk at all! It unmounts and dissappears

Answer (score 0):

```
parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt
parted /dev/sda mkpart primary 0GB 100%
```

Then run the installer.

Comment: The first command gives out a warning : `Information: you may need to update /etc/fstab`, do i ignore this?

Comment: And sorry, this did not work. When i tried to install the system the drive could not be erased to a ext4 format and vanished..

Comment: @sameermanek yes ignore the fstab warning, if Linux could not install to that then you likley have a hardware issue. (you are selecting fresh install; erase eveything right)